# unable to display :active page in my pagination function

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

am using following function to display pagination

```
public function paginationLinks(){
  $outputString = "";
  $q = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos');
  $res = $q->fetch();
  $newsNumber = $res[0];
  $q->closeCursor();
  for($i = 1; $i <= ceil($newsNumber / $this->newsByPage); $i++){
    $outputString .="<li><a href='?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a></li> ";
  }
  return $outputString;
}
```

and this is how i display

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
  <?php echo $news->paginationLinks(); ?>
</ul>
```

now bootstrap doesn't display active page its because of function

how do i add some more option like `next, previous and :active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this .I hope this help you

```
public function paginationLinks(){

    $num_rec_per_page   =   10;
    $outputString = "";

    $page       = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != '') ? trim($_GET['page']) : 1;
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 

    $q              = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos');
    $res            = $q->fetch();
    $total_records  = $res[0];
    $q->closeCursor();

    $total_pages   = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

    $outputString .= "<li><a href='?page=1'>".'|<'."</a></li>"; // Goto 1st page

    if($page > 1){
        $prev          = $page - 1;
        $outputString .= "<li><a href='?page=".$prev."'>Prev</a></li>"; // Goto previous page
    }

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
        $activeClass    =   ($page == $i) ? 'active' : '';
        $outputString .="<li class=".$activeClass."><a href='?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a></li> ";
    }

    if($page < $total_pages){
        $next          = $page + 1;
        $outputString .= "<li><a href='?page=".$next."'>Next</a></li>"; // Goto Next page
    }
    if($page > 1){
        $outputString .= "<li><a href='?page=".$total_pages."'>".'|>'."</a></li>"; // Goto last page
    }
    return $outputString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace your function with this one

```
public function paginationLinks(){
  $outputString = "";
  $crpage = isset($_GET['page']) && trim($_GET['page']) != ''?trim($_GET['page']):1;
  $q = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos');
  $res = $q->fetch();
  $newsNumber = $res[0];
  $q->closeCursor();
  for($i = 1; $i <= ceil($newsNumber / $this->newsByPage); $i++){
    if($crpage == $i){
      $outputString .="<li class='active'><a href='?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a></li> ";
    }else{
      $outputString .="<li><a href='?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a></li> ";
    }
  }
  return $outputString;
}
```

For next or previous see that [link](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html) 
great example for PHP pagination.

Comment: doesn't help nothing happens what about `next, and previous` option

Comment: Dont talk about `mysql_*.` It is deprecated.

Comment: Just convert this code in mysqli extension simple :-)

Comment: checkout this [link](http://bluedogwebservices.com/php-pagination-with-mysqli/) too

Comment: Using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` is inefficient, and can lead to duplicate/skipped pages.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) for how to "remember where you left off".